# MilesJ's Forum Plugin and CakeDC's Users Plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model, cakedc

How can I implement MilesJ's Forum Plugin with CakeDC's Users Plugin?

- The CakeDC Users Plugin works fine.
- The MilesJ's Forum Plugin used to work with the previous self-written Users system (not using a plugin)

The instructions for implement the Forum Plugin at http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum#user-setup. It does not however anticipate the Users system using a Plugin.

This is the model "AppUser" (name forced by CakeDC):

```
App::uses('User', 'Users.Model');

class AppUser extends User {
    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $hasOne = array('Forum.Profile');    
    public $hasMany = array('Forum.Access','Forum.Moderator'));

}
```

I keep on getting the following errors...

```
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "Profile" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "Access" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "Profile" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "Access" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]
```

How can I be sure to have the proper relations between the Forum and Users plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Plugin and Put inside Plugin folder -> `app/Plugin/`
2. Rename the Folder name to 'Forum'.
3. Now go to `app/Plugin/Forum/Config/Schema`

   folder and put all the sql files in to your database with prefix of 'forum_'
4. If your are using auth component then it will work automatically , Once done the above step go to http://example.com/forum/
   5.Then add the following Relationship in your User Model(of your project)

   public $hasOne =  array('Profile' => array(

   ```
           'className' => 'Profile',

           'foreignKey' => 'user_id',

           'dependent' => true,

           'conditions' => '',

           'fields' => '',

           'order' => '',

           'limit' => '',

           'offset' => '',

           'exclusive' => '',

           'finderQuery' => '',

           'counterQuery' => ''

       ),
      )
   ```
5. Then same for Access in has Many Relation ship
6. Then u will get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function image() on a non-object in /var/www/projectname/app/Plugin/Utils/View/Helper/GravatarHelper.php on line 89`

for these put your HTML helper inside that app/Plugin/Utils/View/Helper/

Finally everything needs to work.. Just now i started implementing this.. If you face any error let me know